# Bootstrap Popover Content Duplicates on Each Open

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, popover

I have a popover that is dynamically populated. When I close the popover and re-open it again, the data is duplicated. I think I have isolated part of the solution to `.$tip.find('.popover-content'))`. I am not sure where it should go. I have tested and am not sure as none of the solutions have worked.

Popover Content - 1st Opening:
[image]

Popover Content - 2nd Opening:
[image]

jQuery:

```
$(".listcollect").on("click", function(event) {
    var listID = this.id;

    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/listing_collections/:id/listcollect",
        success: function(result) {
            var arrLen = result.length

            for (var i = 0; i < arrLen; i++) {
                var listingCollectionId = result[i]["id"];

                var $li = $("<li></li>");
                var $a = $('<a class="listing-collection-item"></a>');
                $a.attr("href", "javascript:void(0);");
                $a.data("listing-id", listID);
                $a.data("listing-collection-id", listingCollectionId);
                $a.text(result[i]["name"])
                $li.append($a)
                $(this).next().append($li)
            }
        }.bind(this)
    });

    return true;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group listcollect-wrapper">
   <a onclick="lcflash" class="listcollect dropdown-toggle" data-toggle='dropdown' type="button" id=<%= listing.id %>>Add to Listing Collection <span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$(this)` is an `<ul>`, one way to solve this would be to empty the `<ul>` every time.

Try: `$("ul").empty();` at the beginning. Rather `$(this).empty();` in your case.

Ideal, I'd think you want to clear a pop over list when you close it, but it's your app behavior, you'll know better.

Your code:

```
$(".listcollect").on("click", function(event) {
    var listID = this.id;

    $(this).next().empty();//clears the list items.

    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/listing_collections/:id/listcollect",
        success: function(result) {
            var arrLen = result.length

            for (var i = 0; i < arrLen; i++) {
                var listingCollectionId = result[i]["id"];

                var $li = $("<li></li>");
                var $a = $('<a class="listing-collection-item"></a>');
                $a.attr("href", "javascript:void(0);");
                $a.data("listing-id", listID);
                $a.data("listing-collection-id", listingCollectionId);
                $a.text(result[i]["name"])
                $li.append($a)
                $(this).next().append($li)
            }
        }.bind(this)
    });

    return true;
});
```

Comment: That works, however, the entire button goes away once it is clicked. Is there a way to get the button to stay?

Comment: I didn't guess your button is part of <ul>, you may have to selectively delete the line items or pull the button out of <ul>. Post your html.

Comment: Apologies. The HTML has been added.

Comment: Changed my answer:  $(this).next().empty() should do it. Or $("#dropdown-menu").empty();

Comment: Thanks for your help. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

How do you close the popover? If the content of the popover isn't reset, this sort of behavior is normal as each time you open the popover the data is appended to it.

Depending on how dynamic the data is, you might want to load all the data on page load.

I could also be your back-end, which for some reason could be duplicating the data (but this would be very rare)

Comment: The popover is closed when you click on it again or if you click on another page element.

Comment: If i remember correctly, bootstrap doesn't actually remove that content container. It just removes the css class that made it displayable. So when you click on it again, bootstrap is actually just making is visible again. But then you also add those links to the list again, but that list wasn't empty to begin with